# start SonarQube server with specific jdk

Tags: java, sonarqube

Is there a way to start the SonarQube server (v. 3.7.4) with an specific jdk?

My case: My java-home is set to jdk 1.8, but SonarQube server has some known problems with 1.8. So I want to start the server with jdk 1.7 (without setting my java-home to 1.7).
I couldn't find anything in the bat-files.

OS: Windows 7; SonarQube server version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to edit the `<install_directory>/conf/wrapper.conf` file and update the `wrapper.java.command` property to point to the JDK you want.

Everything is documented in this `wrapper.conf` file.

Comment: FYI, For macOS with Homebrew, the location is `/usr/local/opt/sonarqube/libexec/conf/wrapper.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I set the `SONAR_JAVA_PATH=E:\jdk-17\bin\java.exe` in the environment variable on windows environment variables.

I am using sonar server version 10.1 but I can not find `<install_directory>/conf/wrapper.conf` on the **server**.

Answer (score 0):

wrapper.java.command=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.11/bin/java